# Facebook notifications with unity3d

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I created facebook app, using facebook unity sdk. Now i'm trying to send notification, but only get "failed downloading" error.

```
string href = "mysite.com";
string template = "This is test notification text";

Dictionary<string, string> notificationData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {{"href", href}, {"template", template}};

FB.API("/me/notes", HttpMethod.POST, NotificationCallback, notificationData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send notifications from client because it requires app access token (which you really don't want to share with your players). Send it from your website instead.
OR 
you are talking about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/
that one has no href parameter

Comment: No, i'm talking about [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/). I found there samples, for example, for ios and android sdk, so we can send notifications from client. App access token is needed only ащк canvas apps, but unity app is not canvas or i didn't understand something?

Comment: Yes, unity web client is canvas app anyway. So you need app access token.